# FAT: Directory bread error causes a kernel crash and reboot system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, usb-drive

I'am developing an embedded Linux DLNA server application based on turnkey server, I use a customized Linux system based on openwrt.

The problem is => if I unplug the USB hard disk while my DLNA server build the media database I got many times the following error :

FAT: Directory bread(block 2700948) failed

what causes a kernel crash and reboot system ?
I want to know what is exactly the error mean ? and how can i prevent it  ?

Answer (score 3):

This error message is seen in function [`fs/fat/dir.c:fat__get_entry()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/fat/dir.c#L84)

This error possibly occurred while trying to read a `block = 2700948`, due to some failure or corruption or disk error.

Going forward, I would recommend doing an `{dosfsck,fsck.vfat} -nv -y /path/to/dev/` while the partition is unmounted. Also it would good idea to check your disk for any bad sectors.

Comment: thx for your answer i confirm i find it in fs/fat/dir.c:fat__get_entry() using {dosfsck,fsck.vfat} with unplagged partition can resolve the problem